# fswebcam multiply Devices

Tags: webcam

Im new to Ubuntu.

I try to capture images with fswebcam and 2 webcams.
Operating System is Raspbian on a Bananapi.
GD library is installed.

lsusb find both webcams.

tried following code:

```
sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 /home/bananapi/photos/test.jpg
```

this code take one picture with one cam. If i change the /video0 to /video1 I get a picture of the other cam.

next i tried to take a picture with both cams in one code.

```
sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0,/dev/video1 /home/bananapi/photos/test.jpg /home/bananapi/photos/test2.jpg
```

this one doesnt work. Tried also other combinations without the comma and in an other order. Nothing works.

Someone an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an off-topic question. But here you go anyways (just run it twice on same line)..

```
sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video0 /home/bananapi/photos/test.jpg;sudo fswebcam -d /dev/video1 /home/bananapi/photos/test2.jpg
```